How to optimize this sorting algorithm?
I try to sort elements in a specific way which is basically inherently recursively defined. That is to say which element $x_n$ from the input array assumes index $i(n)$ in the output array is a function of which input elements $x_0$ to $x_{n-1}$ assumed the output indices $i_0$ to $i_{n-1}$.

The big picture
You can think of it as iteratively searching whichever yet unprocessed element from the input, maximizes a cost-function with respect to the set of all already processed elements.

The naive algorithm

So we start by evaluating the cost-function $f(x,q)$ on all but the first input element ($x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1}$), where this evaluation takes a reference-element,- or pothentially several thereof - , which we denote $q$, and during the first iteration, our reference-element is the first input element $x_0$.
The resulting values $f(x_1,q),f(x_2,q), ... ,f(x_{n-1},q)$ are then used as keys by which to,- importantly in-place- sort all elements ($x_1,x_2,..., x_{n-1}$) (in this case in descending order, but that is not important).
In the next iteration, we accordingly evaluate $f(x,q)$ on all but the first two elements ($x_2,x_3,...,x_{n-1}$), this time our (multiple) reference-elements $q$ are the set ${x_0,x_1}$ (note $x_1$ here refers to whichever element has the index 1 as a result of the previous sorting step, not necessarily identical to the element at index 1 in the input array).
We again use values $f(x_2,q),f(x_3,q), ... ,f(x_{n-1},q)$ as keys to in-place sort all elements ($x_2,x_3,...,x_{n-1}$).
We continue in this fashion until we have finished iteration $n-2$, for iteration $n-1$ would imply trying to sort/permute a subarray of length 1, containing only $x_{n-1}$.


Example Python code for the naive algorithm
    import numpy as np
    import potpourri3d as pp3d
    

    def argsort_by_geodesics(points):
    '''Returns indices which sort the input 3D points along axis 0 such as to
        maximize the geodesic distances of each point with respect to all of its
        precursors.
        Expects (points) to be a numpy array of shape (n,3) of distinct 3D
        cartesian coordinates for n points. Note potpourri3d will throw a
        RuntimeError if (n < 31).
        Returns an indexing array of shape (n,) and dtype np.int64.'''
    
    # Get number of input points.
    pointcount = points.shape[0]
    # Setup potpourri3d.PointCloudHeatSolver().
    solver = pp3d.PointCloudHeatSolver(points)
    # Initialize array of geodesic distances to zeros.
    geodesics = np.zeros(pointcount, dtype=np.float64)
    # Initialize index array to permute.
    point_indices = np.arange(pointcount, dtype=np.int64)
    
    # 
    for i in range(1, (pointcount - 1)):
        # Get all points up to, but excluding the current index.
        subarray = point_indices[0:i]
        # Compute geosedic distances for each point in the input pointcloud,
        # w.r.t. the closest among the points in (subarray).
        geodesics = solver.compute_distance_multisource(subarray)
        # Reorder the entries of (geodesics) by indexing with (point_indices),
        # for the indices in latter will have been (partially) permuted after
        # each iteration, while those used by (solver) remain unchanged. Thus we
        # rearrange the results from the solver to compensate for this.
        geodesics = geodesics[point_indices]
        # Overwrite all entries in (geodesics) which correspond to source points
        # by 0 here (it should be save to skip this).
        geodesics[0:i] = 0
        # Set (geodesics) to their absolute values (negative distance is without
        # meaning).
        geodesics = np.absolute(geodesics)
        # Find indices which would sort the array in descending order by
        # geodesic distance. Note we only sort the remainder of the array from
        # the current index (i) onwards.
        order = np.argsort(geodesics[i::])[-1::-1]
        # Rearrange all corresponding entries of (point_indices) by (order).
        point_indices[i::] = point_indices[i + order]

    return point_indices


The obvious
I think it goes without saying this naive implementation is quite wasteful. After all it sorts $({\frac{n²+1}2})-1$ elements when it effectively means to sort $n-1$ elements.

The question
How would I best optimize this? It is worth noting, in principle, the algorithm is very similar to a Fisher-Yates-shuffle.
I think it should be sufficient to find the maximum among $f(x,q)$ in each iteration and move the corresponding element to index $i$, swapping with whichever element was at that index before.
Yet if I replace the 3rd-last line above by something like:
        # Index where (order[0]) is the index of whichever point has maximum
        # geodesic distance. Consider other indices as arbitrary.
        order = np.argpartition(-geodesics[i::], 1)

I get some nonsensical order, while the intention is to yield the exact same order I get from the naive implementation which performs the full sort on the entire remainder of the array in each iteration.
